# Linphone SDK integration returns unknown assembly in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, linphone

I have implemented Linphone in Xamarin forms. It is working fine in iOS but it is crashing in Android.It shows this exception

```
System.DllNotFoundException

linphone.framework/linphone assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

It shows the exception after the following code

```
CoreListener listener = Factory.Instance.CreateCoreListener();
```

Is there any specific Android SDK I need to download for Linphone to work? I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing a minor change in code.

```
 #if WINDOWS_UWP
        public const string BELLE_SIP_LIB_NAME = "bellesip";
                public const string BCTOOLBOX_LIB_NAME = "bctoolbox";
#else
        public const string BELLE_SIP_LIB_NAME = "linphone";
                public const string BCTOOLBOX_LIB_NAME = "linphone";
#endif
```

I changed the `public const string BELLE_SIP_LIB_NAME = "linphone.framework/linphone";` to `public const string BELLE_SIP_LIB_NAME = "linphone";`. I think some libraries are missing in linphone.framework.

Comment: what version of linephone sdk are you using? it this fix for iOS?

Comment: @holopekochan I am currently using Linphone SDK version 5.2.0 alpha version. I didn't test the iOS part yet. I have been working on Android part only.

Answer (score 1):

The main try is the clear/rebuild solution, then try uninstall and reinstall the library, since it's a dllNotFound Exception and if the other ones doesn't work you can try to find your missing DLL from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/) (but for this one you have to figure out which dll file you're missing).

I know these are easy things but maybe you didn't think about it at the time

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with other 3rd party libraries and I found that the linker is causing the problem. Have you tried turning the linker off?

Here's how to do it on VS 2022:

Right-click on your Xamarin.Android project > Properties > Android Options > Linker properties > Set Linking to `None` for your desired configuration

Have a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) for more information on linking

Comment: I tried turning the linker off but it didn't help.

Comment: @JudsonAbraham Well, sorry to disappoint. Do you face the issue on all your configurations (release\debug) ?